# Using PowerShell to trigger Dropbox api saveurl get 400 error

Tags: powershell, dropbox-api

I am following the [API document](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-save_url) here to code my powershell. It seems quite straight forward but I only get 400 invalid request error. May I know what's the problem or how can I further troubleshoot it? I have no clue for the 400 message. I tested simple upload file with PowerShell and works. So the token should be good.

Here is my PowerShell script:

```
$token = Get-Content -Path "c:\token.txt"
$authorization = "Bearer " + $token
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", $authorization)
$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/json')

$body = @"
{
    "path": "/test.mp3",
    "url": "http://sxxxxx.com/today.mp3"
}
"@


    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/save_url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Comment: You have commented away the body `# -Body $body`. Without it it is an invalid request.

Comment: @PalleDue I am sorry. I was trying to debug before post to here. I have tested both with and without Body both have same result. (I have edited the script)

Comment: 400 is a bad input parameter.  Do you have more information from the plaintext message it returns?

Comment: Yes, as dschwartz0815 asked about, the Dropbox API would return a more specific error message in the response body. Print that out for more information.

Comment: I do not get the error msg. Maybe I should improve my script to get the error respond but I don't know how.

Comment: I added try catch in my script. `$_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription` return "Bad Request" only.

Answer (score 0):

My script work after amend the $body part to below:

```
$body = '{
    "path": "/test.mp3",
    "url": "http://sxxxxx.com/today.mp3"
}'
```

It seems I need to pass the parameter as a string instead of json format.